# Drop down menu automatically closing after first click ON ATOM HTML PREVIEW ONLY (NOT BROWSERS)

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm using Atom and have enabled the html preview feature. This problem is isolated to the html preview within Atom and is not happening at all in Chrome or IE.

I have a horizontal main menu in the header. Clicking one of the main menu items is to make a drop down menu appear. The drop down menu should not disappear until the main menu item is clicked a second time. Unfortunately, in my case, the drop down menu disappears automatically after about 1 second. It's as if the page reloads after the click because when the drop down menu disappears, the mouse icon changes from the link select icon (pointer) back to the normal mouse icon (cursor).

I think it has something to do with how the style attribute (display:none;) is retrieved. Here's my code:

```js
var subClick = document.getElementById("mainitemswithdropdown");
var subMenu = document.getElementById("sub")
showHideDrop();
subClick.addEventListener('click', function () {
    showHideDrop();
})

function showHideDrop() {

    if(subMenu.style.display === "none"){
     subMenu.style.display = "block";
    } else {
     subMenu.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

p {
  float: left;
}

#main {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

#mainitems, #mainitemswithdropdown {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left:20px;
}

#sub {
  float:right;
  display: none;
}

#subitems {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <p>Company name</p>

    <ul id="main">
      <li id="mainitems"><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
      <li id="mainitems"><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
      <li id="mainitems"><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
      <li id="mainitems"><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
      <li id="mainitemswithdropdown"><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>


        <ul>
          <div id="sub">
          <li id="subitems"><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
          <li id="subitems"><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
          <li id="subitems"><a href="#">Option 3</a></li>
          </div>
        </ul>

    </ul>
    </header>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately the problem can't be replicated on the stackoverflow code runner.

Notice I've called the function showHideDrop() once in addition to it being called upon the main menu click. If I don't call it once, then the first two clicks won't do anything at all, and then from that point on, it will work just as intended (i.e. click opens, another click closes). Also, after the first click, the mouse icon changes from the link select icon (pointer) back to the normal mouse icon (cursor), as if the page has reloaded or something.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hey, just a headsup, you have HTML errors. An ID must be unique, you've used `subitems` &  `mainitems` multiple times. Think about changing these to `class="subitems"` instead as you can have multiple of one class.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to post my question earlier and ended up figuring it out in the interim. I posted it so I could add the answer here because I think it's a common question for us newbies.

You have to remove the `<a href="#"></a>` tags. These tags act as a link. The "#" specifies an element on the page to which to scroll. So if you have these tags around the main menu item that needs to make the drop down menu appear, the browser MIGHT try to read the link and scroll to that particular position on the page. I believe this is why the menu disappears on the first go through. I don't know why the issue would only happen the first time through though. But nonetheless, removing those tags solved the problem for me.

Comment: You could also use [`preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) and keep the links